# Evaluate $\lim_{t\to1^-}(1-t)\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^r}{1+t^r}$

Tags: limits

$\lim_{t\to1^-}(1-t)\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^r}{1+t^r}$

My approach 
$\frac{t^r}{1+t^r}=t^r-t^{2r}+t^{3r}-\cdots$
$\implies \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^r}{1+t^r}=\frac{t}{1-t}-\frac{t^2}{1-t^2}+\frac{t^3}{1-t^3}-\cdots$
$\implies(1-t)\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^r}{1+t^r}=t-\frac{t^2}{1+t}+\frac{t^3}{1+t+t^2}-\cdots$
$\implies \lim_{t\to1^-}(1-t)\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^r}{1+t^r}=1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\cdots=\ln 2$

Is this correct? Any other more rigorous approach ?

Solution provided by problem poser:

$\lim_{t\to1^-}(1-t)\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^r}{1+t^r}=\lim_{t\to1^-}-\ln t\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+e^{-r\ln t}}$
$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+e^{\frac rn}}$
$=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+e^x}dx=\ln\frac {2e}{1+e}$

This answer seems to be incorrect as

$\frac{t^r}{2}<\frac{t^r}{1+t^r}<t^r\implies \frac{t}{2(1-t)}\le\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^r}{1+t^r}\le\frac{t}{1-t}\implies\frac12\le\lim_{t\to1^-}(1-t)\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^r}{1+t^r}\le 1.$

But $\ln\frac{2e}{1+e}\approx 0.38$

Comment: Also your answer $\ln 2$ and approach is correct. Solution by integrals has an error. The desired integral is $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+e^x}=\log 2$.

Comment: One way would be to show that
$$\lim_{t \uparrow 1} (1 - t) \sum_{r \geq 1} \frac {t^r} {1 + t^r} =
\lim_{t \uparrow 1} (1 - t) \int_1^\infty \frac {t^r} {1 + t^r} dt =
-\lim_{t \uparrow 1} \frac {(1 - t) \ln(1 + t)} {\ln t}.$$
Or to show that the limits can be interchanged in
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1 n \sum_{r \geq 1} \frac 1 {1 + e^{r/n}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{A \to \infty}
 \frac 1 n \sum_{1 \leq r \leq A n} \frac 1 {1 + e^{r/n}} =
\lim_{A \to \infty} \int_0^A \frac {dt} {1 + e^t}.$$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Do you mean the line with the inequalities? Why is it wrong?

Comment: @Maxim: well those inequalities are fine. I have deleted my comment about that.

Comment: Can someone explain the second step of the solution given by the problem poser? I cannot see where it came from.

Comment: @Tony: Note that $(1-t)=\dfrac{1-t}{-\ln t} \cdot (-\ln t) $ and the first factor tends to $1$ so all that remains is $-\ln t$. Further one sets $-\ln t=1/n$ so that $n\to\infty $.