# Find $\lim_{t\to 1^{-}}(1-t)\sum_{r = 1}^\infty \frac{t^r}{t^r+1}$

Tags: limits, summation

> $$\lim_{t\to 1^{-}}(1-t)\sum_{r = 1}^\infty \frac{t^r}{t^r+1}$$

Note: I am a high school student and this problem appeared in my test. So, please try to use methods to solve this problem at a high school level :)

**My Attempt:**

I have honestly no idea how to approach this problem.

I first tried to simplify the summation but didn't find any pattern. By looking at the options given to me ( which were all in ln's and e's )I do get a feel that we may have to integrate at some point. Though I am not sure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really mean $x\to-1$?

Comment: Should surely be $t \to -1$

Comment: edited the question. Does partial fraction help?

Comment: Do you really mean $t\to-1$?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: @HAMIDINESOUMARE: $r$ is just a dummy variable (the index of summation).  I don't see what else can be said about it.  (Other than it ranges over all positive integers.)

Comment: Do you know the answer?  Is it $\ln 2$?

Comment: @Brian Tung Nope!

Comment: Well, I ended up at $-\ln 2$, once I realized I had made an error in sign.  I wonder what's going on here.  As I said in my comment to Tony's answer, I might try to do a quick computation when I get a chance.

Comment: See the same question asked earlier: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3187497/72031

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: write $\frac{1}{1+t^r}$ using the formula for a sum of a geometric series, and change the order of summation.

Full solution:
\begin{align} \lim_{t\rightarrow 1^-} (1-t) \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{t^r}{1+t^r} &= \lim_{t\rightarrow 1^-} (1-t) \sum_{r=1}^\infty t^r \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-t^r)^n = \\
&= \lim_{t\rightarrow 1^-} (1-t) \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{r=1}^\infty (-1)^n t^{(n+1)r} = \\
&= \lim_{t\rightarrow 1^-} (1-t) \sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-1)^n\frac{t^{n+1}}{1-t^{n+1}} = \\
&= \lim_{t\rightarrow 1^-}  \sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-1)^n \frac{1 -t}{1-t^{n+1}} t^{n+1} = \\
&= \lim_{t\rightarrow 1^-}  \sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-1)^n \frac{1}{1+t+t^2+\dots+t^n} t^{n+1} = \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-1)^n \frac{1}{n+1} = \\
&= \ln 2\end{align}

Comment: Did that, but didn't find anything remarkable. :(

Comment: @Tony Ok, I've added athe full solution.

Comment: But the answer given is $\ln \big(\frac{2e}{1+e}\big)$

Comment: Funny, that's where I ended up too, once I realized my error in sign.  Might try a quick computation to see where it's headed.

Comment: Oppss... There is a typo in the question. I have updated it. Sorry... My bad!

Comment: That still only changes the sign back to my answer (which otherwise matches Adam's), and my computation gives $0.69305\ldots$, which is very close to $\ln 2$.  Unless there's a further error in the question, I think the given answer might be wrong.

Comment: @BrianTung: The given answer is wrong. See some discussion on this at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3187497/72031

Comment: @BrianTung The question is as it is copied from my book. There's no further typo in that. I think the given answer might be incorrect.

Comment: @Adam I suggest you edit your answer as per the correct question.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Interesting!

Comment: Corrected the answer to fit the corrected question.